# TypeScript / JS: Not able to get UTC datetime from moment.utc

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

The 4 lines of code below all return the current datetime in CST (where I am) and not in UTC which is what I need.

```
console.log(moment.utc(new Date()).valueOf());
console.log(moment.utc().valueOf());
console.log(moment(new Date()).valueOf());
console.log(moment().valueOf());
```

and these are the values returned:

```
1659553415012
1659553415014
1659553415015
1659553415015
```

or

```
8/3/2022 2:03:35.012000 PM
8/3/2022 2:03:35.014000 PM
8/3/2022 2:03:35.015000 PM
8/3/2022 2:03:35.015000 PM
```

All local time in Houston, Texas, Not UTC.

Can someone please show me how to get UTC?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `format` method, to get the value as a `string`.

```js
const time = moment.utc().format()

// format the date.
console.log(time)


// get the time in miliseconds.
const timeStamp = moment.utc().valueOf();

console.log(timeStamp)

// convert miliseconds to date to ensure it is the correct date.
console.log(new Date(timeStamp));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mina, I'm not trying to get a text format.  I just provided that so you can see the datetime values in a human readable format.  The point being made is the function is returning datetime values in local time and not UTC.  If I use your method, its converted to UTC (great) but its now in a text format (2022-08-03T20:34:05Z) and not a number as milliseconds which is what I need. I need the UTC time in milliseconds.  Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, `moment.utc().valueOf()` get the UTC time with miliseconds, I update the answer please check again.